# Cannot add form for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I'm very new to the forum and to rails and to programming. I'm simply building an app to organise my piano tunings.

I have a Tuning model tuning.rb

```
class Tuning < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tuneds
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tuneds
  validates :Client, presence: true
  validates :Tel, presence: true
  validates :Address, presence: true
  geocoded_by :Address
  after_validation :geocode

  def start_time 
    self.scheduled_date.start
  end
end
```

It has_many tuneds. My tuneds model is tuned.rb

```
class Tuned < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tuning
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tuning
end
```

I would like to show my tuneds form on the tuning show view like so 
[showing form][1]

I have embeded it as such with simple_form

```
<%= simple_form_for :tuneds do |r| %>
  <%= r.input :pitch %>
  <%= r.input :payment %>
  <%= r.input :work_done %>
  <%= r.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Yet it does not add a record to my records column above, which I know works because I can add them through the console. It does not appear in the console or on the show page
[Not showing records on submit][2]

thank you for your help! Evan

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ2vR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87k7A.png

class TuningsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tuning, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tunings
  # GET /tunings.json 
  # how to get them to appear only upcoming Tuning.where('scheduled_date' => Date.today)
  def index

    @tunings = Tuning.all.order('scheduled_date DESC')
    add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path
    add_breadcrumb "All Tunings"
    if params[:search].present?
@tunings = Tuning.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@tunings) do |user, marker|
  marker.lat user.latitude
  marker.lng user.longitude
  @list =Tuning.find(params[:id])
@json = @list.to_gmaps4rails

@tuneds = Tuned.all? { |
|  }
end
    end

  end


Tuning_controller controller
     # GET /tunings/1
      # GET /tunings/1.json
      def show
          add_breadcrumb "Up-coming tunings", :root_path
      end

      def current
        @tuning_current = Tuning.where(['scheduled_date > ?', 1.day.ago]).order('scheduled_date ASC')
           add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path
           add_breadcrumb "Up-coming Tunings", :tunings_current_path

    end



    def bookagain
      six_months = 6.months.ago
      @tuning_bookagain = Tuning.where(['scheduled_date < ?', 6.months.ago])

      add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path
      add_breadcrumb "re-book", :tunings_bookagain_path


    end

    def reports
        add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path
        add_breadcrumb "Reports", :tunings_reports_path
     end

      # GET /tunings/new
      def new
        @tuning = Tuning.new
        add_breadcrumb "Up-coming tunings", :root_path

      end

      # GET /tunings/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /tunings
      # POST /tunings.json
      def create
        @tuning = Tuning.new(tuning_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @tuning.save
            format.html { redirect_to @tuning, notice: 'Tuning was successfully added.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tuning }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @tuning.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
        add_breadcrumb "Up-coming tunings", :root_path


      end


      # PATCH/PUT /tunings/1
      # PATCH/PUT /tunings/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @tuning.update(tuning_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @tuning, notice: 'Tuning was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tuning }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @tuning.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end

        end
          add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
      end

      # DELETE /tunings/1
      # DELETE /tunings/1.json
      def destroy
        @tuning.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to tunings_url, notice: 'Tuning was successfully deleted.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_tuning
          @tuning = Tuning.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def tuning_params
          params.require(:tuning).permit(:Client, :scheduled_date, :Tel, :Address, :Quote, :Type, :Make, :Model, :Work_done, :Work_needed, :Comments, :Paid, :Initial_contact, :Sn)
        end





  Tuned_controller:

class TunedsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @tuning = Tuning.find(params[:tuning_id])
        @tuneds = @tuning.tuneds.create(tuneds.params)
end
end
```

Thanks again

It may well be passing the id to the tuneds model? The error I get is 
‘No route matches [POST] “/tunings/51”

Comment: Can you post the controller code for this?  Also, have you verified that the record gets saved when you submit the form?  Or does it not?

Comment: I don't think it gets saved because it doesn't appear on console when I request Tuned.last I'll add my controllers above

Comment: There are a number of ways you can debug this - when you try to save your HTML form, if you open developer tools, you can check in network requests - what is the http status code being returned - are you receiving a 500 error?

Comment: You can also put a debug statement in your controller method to see what is going on, and why the record isn't being saved.  Two things jump out to me from your code - you're not associating a tuned with a tuning (you don't pass a tuning id in your tuned form) and second, you don't have a create method for tuned in your tuned controller.  If I recall correctly, simple_form is going to extrapolate the create path based on the model you passed into it (which is tuned).  Can you update your ticket with what the server response is when you try to save, and what the error is in your rails server?

Comment: Added the request above for the error

Comment: I managed to solve it I remade the records scaffold and added tuning:references this seemed to link them somehow.